# In ExtJS, event fired before clicking opening a file upload field

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs, dom-events

I have `Ext.form.field.File`, with the `buttonOnly` attribute set to `true`. My question is, is there any event I can execute after I press the 'browse' button but before the file selector pops-up. I want the selector not to pop-up in certain conditions that I want to check. Any advice? I tried `show` and `keydown`. Both of which didn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a little tricky but is what you are looking for:

```
var file =Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...',
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
});

file.mon(file.triggerWrap, {
    click : function(){ 
        alert('yes you can'); 
        file.disable();
        Ext.defer(function(){file.enable();}, 10);        
    }
});​
```

disable() method is used to prevent raising other events (which will prevent open the popup for selecting the file)

Here you have the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/GmAUt/2/

Comment: Interesting, what does `debugger;` do?

Comment: yes, that´s because i did it using chrome and you are using IE. Let me see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very very helpful :)